# <className> <$variable> syntax in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is $e in this code? When we can use this syntax?

```
try {
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    // do more
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: try [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Google was obvisously **not** on the menu today.

Comment: Would sure like to know why this was upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e is the exception that's caught.

Specifically it's a PDOException and only a PDOException.

If any other exceptions are thrown in the try they will not be caught by this block.

[Exceptions in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/exceptions)

### multiple catch blocks

```
try {
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    // do more
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    // PDO Exceptions
    return $e->getMessage();
}
catch( Exception $e ) {
    // all other exceptions will get caught here.
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

### Custom exceptions

One interesting thing you can do when you decide to throw your own exceptions is to create your own custom exception classes.  One [good approach is found in the PHP Manual comments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#91159).

```
class appException extends CustomException{ }
```

### Error exceptions

It's useful to turn PHP Errors (and warnings) into exceptions so you can utilize try/catch to handle all errors in a web app.

```
set_error_handler( create_function( '$a, $b, $c, $d',
    'throw new ErrorException( $b, 0, $a, $c, $d );
    return false;' ),
E_ALL );
```